# Difference between Datagrid and CellTable in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid, celltable

What is the difference between the **Datagrid** and **Celltable**?

I know that following major differences

1. Datagrid provides **RequiresResize.onResize()** functionality while celltable does not give this
2. Datagrid headers are fixed and do not move while scrolling the content. But i want to know is this much difference is enough that they made a whole new widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those and other differences make the need of a new widget.

DataGrid is thought to be included in a `ProvidesResize` hierarchy ([Layout panels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels)), and it explicitly requires to set a fixed width when you dont put it in a `ProvidesResize` widget.

As you can see, in GWT, for certain things, there are two implementations of the same widget depending on the app layout (Basic or Layout panels).

Comment: DataGrid doesn't require that its width to be set. Its a wrong info

Comment: IIRC,  it needs to set a width unless it is in a ProvidesResize widget, but I can be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your listed reasons are enough. They work similarly internally and you can track across google groups discussion for more more or less same information - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/PBhu6RtP4G8

We choose DataGrid as it plays well with responsive design with scroll appearing nicely tucked into grid instead of outside. I do feel CellTable is redundant.